# Posting Json to Jersey Web Service through Ajax

Tags: ajax, json, web-services, jersey

I have an application written in html5 and js, which sends some data in Json like this one:

```
"admin": {
    "id": "1",
    "username": "joninazio",
    "pass": "jotaoene",
    "idPueblo": "30"
},
"fiesta": {
    "fiesta_id": "15",
    "fiesta_nombre": "Fiestas de San Roque, Laudio",
    "fiesta_descr_en": "Festivities in honour of Saint Roch",
    "fiesta_descr_es": "Fiestas en honor a San Roque",
    "fiesta_descr_eu": "San Rokeren omenezko festak",
    "fechafiestaanyo_id": "15",
    "fechafiestaanyo_fecha_inicio": "2013-08-15",
    "fechafiestaanyo_fecha_fin": "2013-08-26",
    "dias_fiesta": [
        {
            "id": "25",
            "fecha": "2013-08-15",
            "nombre": "Txupinazo",
            "descrEn": "Our Lady's festivity",
            "descrEs": "Festividad de Nuestra Señora",
            "descrEu": "Gure Andrearen Jaieguna"
        },
        {
            "id": "26",
            "fecha": "2013-08-16",
            "nombre": "Festividad de San Roke, día del niño",
            "descrEn": "Saint Roch's festivity, children's day",
            "descrEs": "Festividad de San Roke, día del niño",
            "descrEu": "San Rokeren jaieguna, umeen eguna"
        },
        {
            "id": "27",
            "fecha": "2013-08-17",
            "nombre": "Festividad de San Rokezar, día del Joven de Ayer",
            "descrEn": "Saint Rokezar's festivity, former youth's day",
            "descrEs": "Festividad de San Rokezar, día del Joven de Ayer",
            "descrEu": "San Rokezar jaieguna, atzoko gaztearen eguna"
        },
        {
            "id": "28",
            "fecha": "2013-08-18",
            "nombre": "Descanso",
            "descrEn": "Rest day",
            "descrEs": "Descanso",
            "descrEu": "Atseden eguna"
        },
        {
            "id": "29",
            "fecha": "2013-08-19",
            "nombre": "Descanso",
            "descrEn": "Rest day",
            "descrEs": "Descanso",
            "descrEu": "Atseden eguna"
        },
        {
            "id": "30",
            "fecha": "2013-08-20",
            "nombre": "Descanso",
            "descrEn": "Rest day",
            "descrEs": "Descanso",
            "descrEu": "Atseden eguna"
        },
        {
            "id": "31",
            "fecha": "2013-08-21",
            "nombre": "Descanso",
            "descrEn": "Rest day",
            "descrEs": "Descanso",
            "descrEu": "Atseden eguna"
        },
        {
            "id": "32",
            "fecha": "2013-08-22",
            "nombre": "Día de Ajos",
            "descrEn": "Garlic's day",
            "descrEs": "Día de Ajos",
            "descrEu": "Berakatz eguna"
        },
        {
            "id": "33",
            "fecha": "2013-08-23",
            "nombre": "Día de las cuadrillas",
            "descrEn": "Gangs' day",
            "descrEs": "Día de las cuadrillas",
            "descrEu": "Kuadrilen eguna"
        },
        {
            "id": "34",
            "fecha": "2013-08-24",
            "nombre": "Baserritarraren eguna",
            "descrEn": "Farmer's day",
            "descrEs": "Día del baserritarra",
            "descrEu": "Baserritarraren eguna"
        },
        {
            "id": "35",
            "fecha": "2013-08-25",
            "nombre": "Día de las morcillas",
            "descrEn": "Black pudding's day",
            "descrEs": "Día de las morcillas",
            "descrEu": "Odolkien eguna"
        },
        {
            "id": "36",
            "fecha": "2013-08-26",
            "nombre": "Día de la cofradía, día de Roketxu",
            "descrEn": "Brotherhood's day, Roketxu's day",
            "descrEs": "Día de la cofradía, día de Roketxu",
            "descrEu": "Senidetasunaren eguna, Roketxuren eguna"
        }
    ],
    "actos": [
        {
            "id": "1374770783430",
            "fecha": "2013-08-15",
            "nombreEn": "Txupinazo",
            "nombreEs": "Txupinazo",
            "nombreEu": "Txupinazo",
            "descEn": "Txupinazo",
            "descEs": "Txupinazo",
            "descEu": "Txupinazo",
            "horaInicio": "12:00",
            "horaFin": "13:00",
            "lat": "43.143194",
            "lon": "-2.962405100000069"
        },
        {
            "id": "1374770874134",
            "fecha": "2013-08-15",
            "nombreEn": "Pasacalles",
            "nombreEs": "Pasacalles",
            "nombreEu": "Pasacalles",
            "descEn": "Pasacalles",
            "descEs": "Pasacalles",
            "descEu": "Pasacalles",
            "horaInicio": "13:00",
            "horaFin": "14:00",
            "lat": "43.1434506",
            "lon": "-2.9579896999999846"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

This Json data will be caught by a Jersey based Restfull Web service.

The Ajax call is the following:

```
var theUrl = "...";
$.ajax({        

        url: theUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: jsonFiesta,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        complete: function (data){
            //Redireccionar a la página principal de nuevo:
            alert("Ok!!");
            //window.location.replace("./home.html");
        }
});
```

and web service's method is:

```
@POST

@Path("/uploadFiesta")

@Consumes("application/json")

@Produces("application/x-javascript")

public JSONWithPadding uploadFiesta(@QueryParam("callback") String callback,
        String json){

    System.out.println("****vamos a subir esta fiesta");

    boolean bien = false;

    try {
        System.out.println(json);
        bien = new AccessManager().uploadFiesta(new JSONObject(json));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting(); 
    Gson gson = gb.create();

    ReturningClass<Object> c = new ReturningClass<Object>(true);
    c.setData_boolean(bien);
    return new JSONWithPadding(gson.toJson(c), callback);
}
```

What I am doing badly?

I have done a couple a GET calls through Ajax which work:

ajax:

```
jQuery.ajax({

                    url: theUrl,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    jsonp: true,
                    jsonpCallback: "callback",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    error: function (xhr,err) {
                        alert("Error al identificar usuario: " + xhr + "' '" + err);
                    },
                    success: function (data){

                        if(data.response){
                            $("#statusLogin").removeAttr("class");
                            $("#statusLogin").remove();
                            $("#userLoginV").removeAttr("class");
                            $("#userLoginV").removeAttr("value");
                            $("#passLoginV").removeAttr("class");
                            //alert("Se ha identificado satisfactoriamente " + data.object.nombreUsuario);

                            //Inicializar la base de datos de fiestas:
                            //initDb();

                            //Guardar datos en la sesion:
                            login(data.object);

                            //Entramos al home.html
                            window.location.replace("./home.html");

                        }else{
                            $("#userLoginV").attr("class", "error");
                            $("#passLoginV").attr("class", "error");
                            $("#statusLogin").attr("class", "alert alert-error");
                            $("#statusLogin").append("<h4>Error al identificar</h4><p>El usuario y/o la contraseña no son correctas.</p>")
                            alert("Error al identificar usuario. Inténtalo otra vez");
                        }
                    }

                });
```

Web service:

```
@GET

@Path("login/{user}/withPass/{pass}")

@Produces("application/x-javascript")

public JSONWithPadding loginAdministradorFiestas(
        @QueryParam("callback") String callback,
        @PathParam("user") String user,
        @PathParam("pass") String pass
        ){

    System.out.println("***Vamos a tratar de identificar un usuario: ");

    AdministradorFiestas admin = null;
    String resultado = "";
    try {

        admin = new AccessManager().loginAdministradorFiestas(user, pass);
        System.out.println("***Peticion hecha para login!!");
        GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting(); 
        Gson gson = gb.create();

        ReturningClass<AdministradorFiestas> ret = new ReturningClass<AdministradorFiestas>(true, admin);
        resultado = gson.toJson(ret);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new JSONWithPadding(resultado, callback);

}
```

Why the POST is not working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look what it tells me after a few modifications (added JSONObject instead of String the json parameter in Web Service, and removed the jsonp and cross-domain): "XMLHttpRequest cannot load ******/Rest/adminfiestas/uploadFiesta/. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: SOLVED!! Just read these resources: http://mathieuhicauber-java.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/jax-rs-jersey-cors-filter-and-jaxb-list.html, http://blog.usul.org/cors-compliant-rest-api-with-jersey-and-containerresponsefilter/, http://blog.kdecherf.com/2011/06/19/java-jersey-a-cors-compliant-rest-api/